# replaceFirst for a repeating string with every letter being altered

Tags: java, replace

Imagine a scenario where you're changing the bases of DNA to their complement (`A` -> `T`, `T` -> `A`, etc.)

If I wanted to do this in one line, with just a replace command (whether `replaceFirst`, `replaceAll`, etc.), how would I do it or could I without running into a logic trap?

```
System.out.println(X.replaceFirst("A","T").replaceFirst("G","C").replaceFirst("C","G").replaceFirst("T","A");
```

If I were to say AAA as a codon here, it'd come out AAA. Is there a way to code that once a letter has been changed, it can not be changed again by a further command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can but it's quite horrible.

```
String x = "AAA";
System.out.println(x.replace("A", "X")
                    .replace("G", "Y")
                    .replace("C", "G")
                    .replace("T", "A")
                    .replace("X", "T")
                    .replace("Y", "C"));
```

The trick is to replace the letters `A` and `G` with unused other letters and then replace those unused letters at the end.

I recommend you don't really use this code and:

- write `if` statements
- use an `enum` of all 4 bases with their corresponding complement as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Ah, should have thought of that. If I were to do this properly, what would be the best strategy?

Comment: @PTiger17 IMO, the best strategy would be to have an enum `Base`, with 4 values and constructor taking the complementary base.